# Port is open on localhost but remote host reports closed port

Tags: centos, vpn, vps, nmap, pptp

I am trying to setup a pptp server on Centos,

I open port 1723 (pptp port) with no issues when setting up pptp, and I do a nmap scan to confirm that it is open, however when I nmap the server remotely, it doesnt even list port 1723, by which I assume that port 1723 is not accesable

Is there something I am missing, forgetting

p.s., my first time setting up, so I am noob, please forgive any mistakes or missunderstandings and please dont down vote, I really need help and posting on serverfault apparently is of topic for this too...

***UPDATE after @Calvin***

Thank you for your informative response, do you know of anyway I can check where it is being blocked???

Comment: You're already using NMAP, if you're trying to scan that IP from within a network boundary, if it doesn't show up as open, it's closed. As for having a cast iron, this port x is blocked, then you'd need to look at the specific Network/Router Admin, which is safe to assume are managed understandably by a Network Team somewhere.

I don't know of any other way of definitively seeing that without the appropriate access you'd need to view that info. Test to connect from another location, likely to be less secure like a coffee shop. It's very unlikely to be an ISP in the middle of the two locations.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably being blocked by a proxy server/firewall that the remote request has to go through. So for example, you're in one location A, wanting to connect to the other location B (which you've said is setup correctly and open to requests), though the security apparatus at location A have blocked outgoing requests to whatever port range, and likely outside your control unless you know the network administrators to check with them.

Is my first assumption.